# how to return integer (primitive types) as a response json

Tags: json, jersey, integer, jax-rs

I have the following method:

```
public class sum {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public responseObject sumOfTwo(@QueryParam("a") int a, @QueryParam("b") int b) {
        return new responseObject(a+b);
    }
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement
class responseObject{
    public int res;
    public responseObject(int res){
        this.res = res;
    }
    public responseObject(){
        //default C'tor
    }
    public int getRes(){
        return this.res;
    }
}
```

This returns `{"res":"value of a+b"}` with the value in quotes. I want it to return the value as an integer, without quotes, but I'm getting it as a string. How can I serialize/deserialize it to output an integer only?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with "Integer" instead of primitve "int"?
What is your JSON provider?

Most JSON serialisation problems I have seen can be dealt with by changing the Json Provider from the default (MOxy) Json Provider to Jackson. It will handle bean serialization just like you think it will. MOxy on the other hand, is often problematic to my experience.

How to use Jackson with Jersey : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson

Comment: Integer instead of int ins't affecting.
I'm using the default Json provider, and trying now to work with the Jackson.